# Calibrating Displays in Boot Camp 3.0 on MacBook with external display

Tags: windows-7, display, boot-camp, calibration

The LED display on my MacBook Pro is very blue-ish without correction. In OS X the advanced mode of the display color calibration tool is excellent and I can largely color-correct the display. Windows 7 incorporates a color calibration tool but it is less powerful. It largely consists of a software gamma correction tool and color charts to use with the hardware controls on your display (which don't exist on a notebook or an apple external display). How can I color-correct Windows in Boot Camp to match the OS X correction without using a Spyder or other special calibration hardware?

Comment: +2 for a good tip, -1 for it not being a question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Vista, Microsoft bundles support for ICC color profile calibration with the "Windows Color System." Even though Vista doesn't include a tool to create ICC profiles and the tool in Windows 7 is very basic, you can load any profiles that you generate by other means.

If you use the advanced display calibration wizard in OS X, it will generate ICC profiles for you. If you save the profiles for "all users" they will be stored in a central location. Then you can load and use them in Windows because Boot Camp 3.0 provides HFS+ drivers to mount the OS X system volume.

After you do the calibration in OS X, restart inot Windows. The calibrated ICC files should be readable on your "Macintosh HD" volume. On my machine they are in E:\Library\ColorSync\Profiles\Displays.

Right-click on the .icc files and choose "Install Profile". Then you can use Control Panel > Display > Ajust resolution > Advanced Settings > Color Managment to load the appropriate ICC profiles for each monitor. You can use the Advanced tab to set the default color profile per display for all users.